# How do I set the text color of primary raised buttons for React Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, styling, material-ui, palette

I've been able to customize a number of color and spacing related properties of Material-UI by passing a custom muiTheme property, but there doesn't seem to be a palette element which corresponds to the text color for buttons in any specific state.

In this case, I am using a primary1Color of #4275c7 for the muiTheme - and primary button text is showing as black. Given this primary color, white text would look better and be more readable.

I have already tried setting palette.primaryColor/primaryTextColor, button.primaryTextColor, and raisedButton.textColor/primaryColor/primaryTextColor. None of them are driving button text coloring. Is there an obvious property I am missing, or is a different kind of config needed?

For reference, here's my current muiTheme declaration:

```js
export const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
  borderRadius: 2,
  spacing: {
    iconSize: 24,
    desktopGutter: 24,
    desktopGutterMore: 32,
    desktopGutterLess: 16,
    desktopGutterMini: 8,
    desktopKeylineIncrement: 64,
    desktopDropDownMenuItemHeight: 32,
    desktopDropDownMenuFontSize: 15,
    desktopDrawerMenuItemHeight: 48,
    desktopSubheaderHeight: 48,
    desktopToolbarHeight: 56
  },
  palette: {
    primary1Color: '#4275c7',
    primaryTextColor: MaterialColors.white,
    primaryColor: MaterialColors.white,
    primary2Color: MaterialColors.cyan700,
    primary3Color: MaterialColors.grey400,
    accent1Color: MaterialColors.pinkA200,
    accent2Color: MaterialColors.grey100,
    accent3Color: MaterialColors.grey500,
    textColor: MaterialColors.darkBlack,
    secondaryTextColor: (0, MaterialColorManipulator.fade)(MaterialColors.darkBlack, 0.54),
    alternateTextColor: MaterialColors.white,
    canvasColor: MaterialColors.white,
    borderColor: MaterialColors.grey300,
    disabledColor: (0, MaterialColorManipulator.fade)(MaterialColors.darkBlack, 0.3),
    pickerHeaderColor: MaterialColors.cyan500,
    clockCircleColor: (0, MaterialColorManipulator.fade)(MaterialColors.darkBlack, 0.07),
    shadowColor: MaterialColors.fullBlack
  },
  button: {
    height: 45,
    // primaryTextColor: MaterialColors.white,
  },
  // raisedButton: {
  //   color: MaterialColors.black,
  //   textColor: MaterialColors.white,
  //   primaryColor: MaterialColors.black,
  //   primaryTextColor: MaterialColors.white,
  // },
});
```

And here is a sample raised primary button:

[image]

Comment: What material-ui version are you using?

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned in the post. This project is on v0.18.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using v1?  If so, the text color for primary buttons is defined in the component's stylesheet using *theme.palette.getContrastText*:

```
  raisedPrimary: {
    color: theme.palette.getContrastText(theme.palette.primary[500]),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary[500],
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary[700],
    },
  },
```

This finds the color that will contrast best with your chosen primary color.  If you don't want this, you could create a custom component that wraps Button and [override the classes](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/overrides#overriding-with-classes) of your choosing from its [CSS API](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/component-api/button#css-api).

Comment: Thanks Ken! I began this project with v1, but kept running into issues and have now reverted to v0.18. For example, in  V1, checkboxes no longer seem to have a "label" property and wrapping them with an external label tag resulted in vertical alignment issues. In your experience, is V1 stable enough to incorporate in production projects without fighting with simple, obvious things at every step?

Comment: @TronPaul it's a beta and a rewrite.  There are going to be things that shake out, but the components are much easier to work with and style in v1, so we've decided to use it in our projects and contribute to the project as needed.

Comment: Fair enough. Marking this answer as accepted, and I'll experiment with rolling this project forward again to V1.